# What do you mean by Sorting?

Tags: c++, sorting

First of all I'm 14, and only have 2yrs experience of coding. 6 months experience in C++. I know basic Python, Java and C++.

I have 3 questions:

1) Which is the quickest sorting algorithm?

2) Is there an in-built function for sorting?

3) What is this thing called time complexity?

Comment: 1) Depends on the data being sorted, read about sorting algorithms (v.g. Wikipedia), 2) Depends of the language, 3) Check out the web (v.g. Wikipedia)

Comment: Have a look at this [time complexity tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6mKVRU1evU).

Comment: Your question doesn't meet the criteria for this site, that's why you get downvotes. Please don't be disappointed, just follow @SJuan76`s advice. There's lots of information on wikipedia. It's great to see a 14 year old showing real interest in 3 different programming languages. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1) Which is the quickest sorting algorithm?
Since 2011 Two-Pivot-Quicksort (Yaroslavski) is fastest and 10 % faster than quicksort. It is in the java library. It should use insertion sort for small sublists.

2) Is there an in-built function for sorting?

No, but most libraries contain fast sorting functions

3) What is this thing called time complexity?

It is a rough measure for the estimated time needed to perform the algorithm. Quicksort (and 2-Pivot-Quicksort) need O(n ln n) which means that for an unsorted list of lenght n (n=300) you need some multiple of n*ln(n) steps (300*ln300~1711) to complete the sort.
The factor is not specified and implicitly contained in the notation O() (google for Big-Oh!)